# Change the maximum width OR maximum height of a form in .net

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, forms, size

I've been meaning to ask this question for a while.

It appears that if I want to set a maximum width of a form then I have to set a maximum height as well.

Is this right?

If so, which of the multitude of variables do I use, in this situation, to set the maximum form height to the height of the window?

Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds?, Screen.GetWorkingArea(New Point(0, 0))?

Eta: From further investigation, I think PrimaryScreen.Bounds and GetWorkingArea are the same.

Also, having thought a little more, should I put Int32.MaxValue into the height property instead of the max height of the window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do have to set the max width and height together using a Size instance.  If you do not want to limit one of the dimensions, you might want to consider using System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.MaxWindowTrackSize to get the max for the "unlimited" dimension.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that because MaxWindowTrackSize limits the maximum size to the size of the display area. Although I've never found the need, I think a window is sometimes sized to larger than the screen area.
It's annoying that the max size isn't defaulted to (-1,-1), where -1 means unlimited.